# How to show directions on the map?

Tags: leaflet, mapbox, direction

I am using Mapbox, Leaflet.
Via Mapbox Walking directions I create directions and save origin and destination markers coordinates; Then I want to show this created direction. So I do following:

```
<script>
        var start = JSON.parse($('#start_field').val());
        var finish = JSON.parse($('#finish_field').val());
        L.mapbox.accessToken = 'qwerty';
        var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'mapbox.streets', {
            zoomControl: false
        }).setView([42.8580536, 74.6224754], 12);
        L.Routing.control({
            waypoints: [
                L.latLng(start.lat, start.lng),
                L.latLng(finish.lat, finish.lng)
            ]
        }).addTo(map);

        var start_marker = L.marker([start.lat, start.lng], {
            draggable: false
        }).addTo(map);

        var finish_marker = L.marker([finish.lat, finish.lng], {
            draggable: false
        }).addTo(map);
    </script>
```

But I have an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'control' of undefined

Comment: Are you hosting this on github? Can you share a link to your project page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow `L.Routing` doesn't exist.  Are you using Leaflet Routing Machine?  Make sure you're loading the script: `<script src="leaflet-routing-machine.js">`.